# Protocol-Delegate pattern not notifying View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, delegates, protocols

My `Model` saves data to Firestore. Once that data is saved, I'd like it to alert my `ViewController` so that a function can be called. However, nothing is being passed to my `ViewController`.

This is my `Model`:

```
protocol ProtocolModel {
    func wasDataSavedSuccessfully(dataSavedSuccessfully:Bool)
}

class Model {

    var delegate:ProtocolModel?

    func createUserAddedRecipe(
        docId:String,
        completion: @escaping (Recipe?) -> Void) {

            let db = Firestore.firestore()

                do {
                    try db.collection("userFavourites").document(currentUserId).collection("userRecipes").document(docId).setData(from: recipe) { (error) in

                        print("Data Saved Successfully") // THIS OUTPUTS TO THE CONSOLE
                        
                        // Notify delegate that data was saved to Firestore
                        self.delegate?.wasDataSavedSuccessfully(dataSavedSuccessfully: true)
                     }
                }
                catch {
                    print("Error \(error)")
                }
    }
}
```

The `print("Data Saved Successfully")` outputs to the console, but the delegate method right below it doesn't get called.

And this is my `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var model = Model()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        model.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: ProtocolModel {
    func wasDataSavedSuccessfully(dataSavedSuccessfully: Bool) {
        if dataSavedSuccessfully == true {
            print("Result is true.")
        }
        else {
            print("Result is false.")
        }
        
        print("Protocol-Delegate Pattern Works")
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing from this pattern? I haven't been able to notice anything different in the articles I've reviewed.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be calling your delegate method inside your `catch`?  You should also make that delegate property `weak`, but that's a separate topic.

Comment: have you called `createUserAddedRecipe`. I would recommend to store  `let db = Firestore.firestore()` as a property of your model

Comment: I wonder where do you call createUserAddedRecipe method?

Comment: I test something like your code and everything works like charm, if you want I can share with you

Comment: @RezaKhonsari I would love to see your example!

Comment: @amirbt17 sure I will share with you as my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I test your code and simulate something like that

```
import UIKit

protocol ProtocolModel {
    func wasDataSavedSuccessfully(dataSavedSuccessfully:Bool)
}

class Model {
    
    var delegate:ProtocolModel?
    
    // I use this timer for simulate that firebase store data every 3 seconds for example
    var timer: Timer?
    
    func createUserAddedRecipe(
        docId:String) {
            
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                self.delegate?.wasDataSavedSuccessfully(dataSavedSuccessfully: true)
            })
        }
}

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    var model = Model()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        model.delegate = self
        // Call this method to register for network notification
        model.createUserAddedRecipe(docId: "exampleId")
    }
}

extension NavigationController: ProtocolModel {
    func wasDataSavedSuccessfully(dataSavedSuccessfully: Bool) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

so you can see the result as image below, my delegate update controller that conform to that protocol.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @RezaKhonsari! Your example helped me uncover that I set up my Protocol-Delegate pattern correctly. If I call the delegate in my ViewController's `viewDidLoad()`, my delegate method gets called. BUT if I call it in my ViewController's `@IBAction func`, it does NOT get called. Do you know why that may be the case?

Comment: UPDATE: it actually does work in my `@IBAction func`. What does NOT work is when it's being called within _some_ functions in my `Model`. I'll continue digging.

Comment: Wow so it was a very silly mistake. I was calling `Model().function()`. When I changed it to `model = Model()` and `model.function()` it worked. Thank you so much for your guidance!

Comment: @amirbt17 you're welcome, if my answer helps you, could you please mark my answer as correct one and also upvote it. thanks